# We need to disambiguate the [wds] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[wds](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wds) stands for:

- Windows Desktop Search
- Windows Deployment Services
- Wireless Distribution System

All of these are used here, so we need to figure out how to split up the tag.

Suggestions?

To get this out of the way, [windows-deployment-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-deployment-services) and [wireless-distribution-system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-distribution-system) are too long. Max length for tags is 25 chars.

Comment: There are 6 "Windows Deployment Services" questions, 15 "Wireless Distribution system" tags and 0 for "Windows Desktop Search". I think it would be easy to do. Is there a way to suggest the disambiguated tabs when someone tries to tag "wds"?

Comment: @washbow No, we can't do this. Go vote for this suggestion to be implemented though: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags) :)

Comment: [tag:wds] referring to [tag:Windows-Desktop-Search] should be retagged to [tag:Windows-Search]

Answer (score 7):

How about tagging the deployment questions simply as [windows-deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-deployment) and letting wireless distribution keep [wds](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wds) since it seems to be the most common/popular?

Windows Deployment Services is also a bit specific. That refers to the role installed on the server which responds to PXE boot requests and serves up the images. Other than that, it doesn't really do much. Out of all six tagged questions, none of them refer to only Windows Deployment Services, and all deal with Windows Deployment as a whole.

It would be odd to have a question about Windows Deployment Services and not involve MDT, WAIK, or a slew of other tools used for Windows Deployment, especially on Super User. I don't think it would cause any confusion to tag these as simply [windows-deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-deployment):

#### Windows Deployment Services Questions:

[Resealing windows XP stops PXE working](https://superuser.com/questions/504691/resealing-windows-xp-stops-pxe-working)

[How do I create a bootable .wim from Win 7 system image?](https://superuser.com/questions/467696/create-a-bootable-wim-from-win-7-system-image)

[Phantom hard drive after deploying latest Windows 7 image from WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/317928/phantom-hard-drive-after-deploying-latest-windows-7-image-from-wds)

[How do I perform Windows image deployment from a configured laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/356280/can-i-do-windows-image-deployment-from-a-configured-laptop)

[Imaging HP Laptops using WDS server](https://superuser.com/questions/421793/imaging-hp-laptops-using-wds-server)

[How to control the PXE boot behaviour from a Windows Deployment Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/439036/how-to-control-the-pxe-boot-behaviour-from-a-windows-deployment-server)

#### Questions tagged [deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deployment) that fit [windows-deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-deployment):

[Recover application installation parameters from MDT deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/499890/recovering-application-installation-parameters-from-mdt-deployment)

[System Reserved Partition has Drive Letter After Applying a WIM Image with ImageX](https://superuser.com/questions/499430/system-reserved-partition-has-drive-letter-after-applying-a-wim-image-with-image)

[New Task Sequence Wizard](https://superuser.com/questions/497878/new-task-sequence-wizard)

[Can WIM Images be used to perform an upgrade install?](https://superuser.com/questions/470314/can-wim-images-be-used-to-perform-an-upgrade-install)

[Integrate Office 2010 (PKC Version) into Windows for deployment?](https://superuser.com/questions/464262/integrate-office-2010-pkc-version-into-windows-for-deployment)

[Windows 7 universal and updated ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/463349/windows-7-universal-and-updated-iso)

[How to boot an WIM image?](https://superuser.com/questions/441294/how-to-boot-an-wim-image)

[How to control the PXE boot behaviour from a Windows Deployment Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/439036/how-to-control-the-pxe-boot-behaviour-from-a-windows-deployment-server)

[Sysprepped image will not complete setup](https://superuser.com/questions/429003/sysprepped-image-will-not-complete-setup)

[Imaging HP Laptops using WDS server](https://superuser.com/questions/421793/imaging-hp-laptops-using-wds-server)

[Deploying Windows Embedded Standard with MDT - Missing language pack during installation](https://superuser.com/questions/414266/deploying-windows-embedded-standard-with-mdt-missing-language-pack-during-inst)

[TaskbarLinks in Unattend.xml Windows 7 deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/382352/taskbarlinks-in-unattend-xml-windows-7-deployment)

[Installing software after .wim image](https://superuser.com/questions/358657/installing-software-after-wim-image)

[Going from imagex/AIK to WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/358123/going-from-imagex-aik-to-wdt)

[AutoLogin in Answer File](https://superuser.com/questions/358092/autologin-in-answer-file)

[Modifying/Testing Image/AnswerFile](https://superuser.com/questions/357785/modifying-testing-image-answerfile)

[Image -> Answer File -> Sysprep -> Image?](https://superuser.com/questions/357683/image-answer-file-sysprep-image)

[How do I perform Windows image deployment from a configured laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/356280/can-i-do-windows-image-deployment-from-a-configured-laptop)

[Disable Windows 7 auto-login after deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/341139/disable-windows-7-auto-login-after-deployment)

[Is sysprep no longer useful for full removal of items including their install parts?](https://superuser.com/questions/339598/is-sysprep-no-longer-useful-for-full-removal-of-items-including-their-install-pa)

[Deploying Bitlocker via Unattended OS Installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/322378/deploying-bitlocker-via-unattended-os-installation)

[Activate Excel Add-Ins as part of Deployment?](https://superuser.com/questions/322032/activate-excel-add-ins-as-part-of-deployment)

[Enable Bitlocker and Save Key to Network Share with Unattend?](https://superuser.com/questions/318492/enable-bitlocker-and-save-key-to-network-share-with-unattend)

[Phantom hard drive after deploying latest Windows 7 image from WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/317928/phantom-hard-drive-after-deploying-latest-windows-7-image-from-wds)

[Adding and removing machine from domain, whats happening?](https://superuser.com/questions/316623/adding-and-removing-machine-from-domain-whats-happening)

[Sysprep - XPsp3 - Product Key](https://superuser.com/questions/212666/sysprep-xpsp3-product-key)

[Image multiple Windows 7 computers from OEM install?](https://superuser.com/questions/205176/image-multiple-windows-7-computers-from-oem-install)

[Is there a good alternative to sysprep?](https://superuser.com/questions/202503/is-there-a-good-alternative-to-sysprep)

[Creating an image from a VMware installation of Windows for deploying to real physical machines](https://superuser.com/questions/173195/creating-an-image-from-avmware-installation-of-windows-for-deploying-to-real-ph)

[Deploy Windows (2008 R2) onto a Linux server.... with no physical access to the machine](https://superuser.com/questions/169786/deploy-windows-2008-r2-onto-a-linux-server-with-no-physical-access-to-the)

[Windows 7 - Setting up the default taskbar items](https://superuser.com/questions/97894/windows-7-setting-up-the-default-taskbar-items)

[Windows 7 - Setting up the default taskbar items](https://superuser.com/questions/97894/windows-7-setting-up-the-default-taskbar-items)

[What tool can I use to create and deploy Windows 7 images?](https://superuser.com/questions/77821/what-tool-can-i-use-to-create-and-deploy-windows-7-images)

[Icon on user account desktop before the user has logged in.](https://superuser.com/questions/520691/icon-on-user-account-desktop-before-the-user-has-logged-in)

[Resealing windows XP stops PXE working](https://superuser.com/questions/504691/resealing-windows-xp-stops-pxe-working)

[Windows Deployment Server-RAID Controller](https://superuser.com/questions/562768/windows-deployment-server-raid-controller)

Comment: Good idea! We'd need to check if any `[deployment]` questions should be `[windows-deployment]`.

Comment: @slhck There's, um, a few...

Comment: I wish we had an option to mass-retag a list of questions. Thanks for summarizing them though!

Comment: @slhck There's probably a few more relevant questions under things like [imagex] and [sysprep] etc. Should I go ahead and start digging through stuff and retaging?

Comment: I second that notion, we need a windows deployment tag. disk cloning has gone the way of the floppy disk. MDT / WDS is the future of windows deployment. The confusion seems to be between WDS and the WDS server role used for PXE booting.

Comment: @MDTGuy Yeah I thought you might like that tag. :P

Comment: @Tanner Yeah, we need to clean that up. Windows Deployment rules! Death to Clonezilla!

Answer (score -1):

Easy.  Blacklist [WDS] because out of context it is a meaningless tag (as opposed to [iscsi] which is likely to only ever have one meaning).  Force the question asker or editors to use something more meaningful.  Mission complete.

[Edit]
I forgot how to do tag links.  Sorry.

Comment: And what tags do we create in their place?

Comment: Windows Desktop Search -> "Search", Windows Deployment Services -> "Win-Deployment-Svc", and Wireless Distribution System -> "Wireless-Dist-Sys"